# Not able to connect to atom.io for themes and packages

Tags: proxy, atom-editor

I believe my work proxy is preventing me from being able to add themes and packages to Atom.  From the preferences menu, I get:

Fetching featured packages and themes failed. **Hide output…**

```
tunneling socket could not be established, cause=140499728967552:error:140770FC:SSL  routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:766:
```

Is it possible to make it use my `$https_proxy` variable?  Is there some way to configure it to not use https?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can configure your proxy settings in `~/.atom/.apmrc` (or `Atom\resources\app\apm\node_modules\atom-package-manager\.apmrc` in Windows).  Per the [apm README](https://github.com/atom/apm/blob/master/README.md#behind-a-firewall):

> If you are using a proxy you can configure apm to use it by setting the https-proxy config in your `~/.atom/.apmrc` file like so:

```
https-proxy = https://9.0.2.1:0
```

Comment: One more notice: if you use CNTLM or just use 'localhost' as the proxy, you must specify it with http:// otherwise it won't work.

http-proxy = http://localhost:3128

Comment: I'm using CNTLM and I edited ~/.atom/.apm/.apmrc to set http-proxy.  Every time I launch atom it deletes this line.

Comment: @eric.frederich use ~/.atom/.apmrc

Comment: @Alex Mooney In my computer where the atom 1.0.3 was installed, I can't find the atom-package-manager in the node-modules directory.

Comment: For me, in `https-proxy ` option, use `http` instead of `https` make it work.

Answer (score 25):

It seems that as of Atom 1.0, there are some components that respect the `http-proxy` and `https-proxy` variables, and others that don't.  For example, the initial check for the version of Atom works, but the check for packages doesn't seem to respect the `http-proxy` or `https-proxy` settings.

I was able to get Atom working with Fiddler as my proxy (on 127.0.0.1:8888) by running the following commands (on Windows):

```
apm config set proxy http://127.0.0.1:8888
apm config set strict-ssl false
```

I did not need to set `http-proxy` or `https-proxy`.  I don't know if these settings have been deprecated or not, but they don't seem to work reliably in 1.0.  The setting `proxy` works (and upgrades itself to TLS 1.2 automatically).

The entirety of my `%USERPROFILE%\.atom\.apmrc` file is:

```
strict-ssl=false
proxy=http://127.0.0.1:8888/
```

Comment: This is the only answer that worked for me ! I have removed the **http-proxy , https-proxy** and restarted atom !!! Thanks !

Comment: Your answer worked! Thanks! 
Except I needed to change the ip address and port to my company's own proxy ip and port

Answer (score 3):

I was getting this error on Windows 7 fro Atom 1.0, when trying to look up packages.
In my case the issue was resolved by setting https-proxy variable to use http protocole instead of https. so both of the following parameters have exact same value.

> here are the values from ~.atom.apmrc file

`proxy=http://[host]:[port]/
 https-proxy=http://[host]:[port]/`

the answer by @NYCdotNet below that suggested to use

```
strict-ssl=false
```

didn't work as i was able to lookup some packages but installation failed with timeout error from GIT.

Answer (score 2):

Atom will use your shell's proxy variables (like `$https_proxy`) if you start Atom from a shell that has these variables set. You need to have the Atom command line tools installed for that to work.

From a shell, you can simply type `atom` to open the editor for the current directory. It will use all environment variables from this shell, including the proxy variables.

I find this a lot easier than setting the variables in the config file.

Answer (score 2):

I edited the `~/.atom/.apmrc` file to set my proxy as mentioned by @AlexMooney, but still got errors. 
The solution was to write

```
proxy = http://host:port
strict-ssl = false
```

in that `~/.atom/.apmrc` file.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows you can easily configure the https-proxy via command line:

```
amd config set https-proxy https://9.0.2.1:0
```

It should be stored under C:\Users\...\.apm in file .apmrc

See userconfig with command

```
amd config list
```

Answer (score 1):

To config Proxy for Atom to install new pakage, just open CMD and run these commands:

- apm config set strict-ssl false
- apm config set proxy your_proxy
- apm config set your_proxy

Answer (score 0):

I am working behind a proxy server and spent about half a day on this issue, setting https_proxy as well as http_proxy didn't make a difference.

What did it for me was setting the proxy from the cmd line like so:

apm config set proxy http://myproxyaddress:port

I still can't install packages through Atom's gui, but doing it through the cmd line works fine. That I'll take.

I later realised I could've switched to the wifi and got it to work immediately...