# How to configure Atom to use proxy file (pac) settings?

Tags: windows, configuration, proxy, atom-editor, pac

On Windows, is it possible to configure Atom to use the system default proxy instead of manually specifying the proxy settings in the *.apmrc* file?

---

I recently started using the [atom-editor](/questions/tagged/atom-editor) for Windows (**Windows 7 Pro**) and so far I like it.  I've been searching for some time to try and get the editor to be able to connect to the outside world and haven't met with any success.

Our network (I'm not a network expert) is configured to use a proxy server (internal) to access the internet.  On my system, this is accomplished in the proxy settings with an 'Automatic Configuration Script', for example: `http://internal-server-name/sub-dir/file-name.pac`.

Many resources have suggested manually setting the proxy information in the *.apmrc* file:

- [Not able to connect to atom.io for themes and packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24936889/not-able-to-connect-to-atom-io-for-themes-and-packages)
- here:https://discuss.atom.io/t/is-there-any-proxy-settings/710/19
- https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/1807

**These do not answer my question as I need the system defaults to work**

I tried to configure Atom to do this same thing but when I change the *.apmrc* file to have:

```
http-proxy = http://internal-server-name/sub-dir/file-name.pac
https-proxy = https://internal-server-name/sub-dir/file-name.pac
strict-ssl = false
```

I get the following error (presumably because the above address is not the proxy itself):

```
tunneling socket could not be established, cause=Parse Error
```

When I leave the *.apmrc* file unmolested, I receive the following error when trying to view packages:

```
getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
```

Even if I had a proxy server IP address and port number to specify, not only would i not want to hard-code my credentials in a config file but I'm pretty sure the authentication is somehow set up to use Kerberos tokens anyway, so I wouldn't be able to specify them at all.

Interestingly the Atom updates says that my installed packages (out of the box) are up to date, which would seem to indicate that this portion is working while the packages and themes do not.

---

Here are some screenshots for reference:

**No *.apmrc* changes**
[image: No .apmrc changes]

**Proxy server specified in *.apmrc***
[image: Proxy server specified in .apmrc]

### Edit 08/31/2015

In response to some of the feedback, I tried to view the **.pac** file and extract the proxy server address information.  I was able to get the information about the proxy out of the file and put it in the *.apmrc* file but it had no affect on the outcome (I still receive the same errors).  I have also since tried using **CNTLM** to no avail.

Also note that my proxy **does** require authentication as stated above.  I've been doing further research on this issue and it may be a combination of proxy settings for the `APM` and proxy settings for GitHub.  See the following relevant article:

- https://discuss.atom.io/t/error-running-apm-install-behind-proxy/14812

Ideally, I'd like a solution that doesn't require a complete machine configuration or a fragile multi-config file setup.

Answer (score 6):

A `.pac` file is just a javascript file that browsers can run to programmatically determine which proxy to use. This is useful if your network needs to use different proxies to access different resources. If you open up that file, you'll probably be able to make sense of it (it's just javascript, after all) and figure out which proxy your network is using for general access to the web. Set that as your proxy in your `.apmrc` file and it should work.

Things get more complicated if your proxy requires some kind of authentication. If that's your problem, let me know. I have some experience dealing with it.

---

#### Authenticating

OK, so you need to authenticate. Then your situation is probably pretty similar to mine. You are correct in using CNTLM, we just need to configure it properly. Your `cntlm.ini` file will look something like this:

```
Username    <your windows username>
Domain      <your domain name>
Password    <leave this blank>
PassLM      <get this by running `cntlm -H` on the command line>
PassNT      <get this by running `cntlm -H` on the command line>
PassNTLMv2  <get this by running `cntlm -H` on the command line>

Proxy       <Your proxy address like ip_address:port>
Proxy       <If you have multiple proxies, you may list them each on a new line>

NoProxy     localhost, 127.0.0.*, <any others that should bypass the proxy>

Listen      <a local port to listen on (I use 53128)>
```

There's something a bit funny that you should know about this file (`cntlm.ini`). When you install cntlm, it's included in the program's folder but it actually will only work if it's located at `C:\Program Files (x86)\cntlm\cntlm.ini`. I guess it's probably more accurate to say that it should be in the `cntlm` folder inside the `PROGRAMFILES` directory so you should double check that this is the case.

Anyway, having done all that, you can now start `cntlm` (instructions in the readme). Next, you need to configure `apm` to actually use your local proxy. Your `.apmrc` should look like this:

```
http-proxy = http://localhost:<port # from cntlm.ini>
https-proxy = https://localhost:<port # from cntlm.ini>
strict-ssl = false
```

You'd think this would be enough but there's more that might help. I had a lot of problems with `npm` until I found that `https` doesn't work well through `cntlm` so I needed to change my registry from `https://registry.npmjs.org/` to `http://registry.npmjs.org/`. Since `apm` also uses the same registry, I decided to change that too:

```
apm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

And then... it seemed to also help to go into Atom's `config.cson` and set `core.proxy` to `http://localhost:<port # from cntlm.ini>`

And after all that, I'd expect things to work for you. If it's cool and fine and Atom is working well, there's one more thing that you might want to do that will make most (all?) other apps (npm, git, etc) work well. On the command line, run:

```
netsh winhttp set proxy localhost:<port # from cntlm.ini> "localhost, 127.0.0.*"
```

This will save you the trouble of configuring most (all?) other apps one-by-one. For some reason, `apm` does need to be configured specifically. I guess it doesn't use the winhttp settings for some reason? I don't know the answer to that.

#### New Info 2016/03/18

I recently noticed that there's one additional thing you might need to do for some apps. You should set the following environment variables to your local proxy as well:

```
HTTP_PROXY
HTTPS_PROXY
FTP_PROXY
http_proxy
https_proxy
ftp_proxy
```

It may seem like overkill to set both upper and lower case but I recently installed MSys2 and found that it looks for the lower case versions so just set them all and save yourself some trouble.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  I did not know this about the `.pac` file, so thanks for that info.  I tried your suggestion but it did not work (please see the updated question).  Also, the proxy does require authentication.

Comment: I added some details about using cntlm. Let me know if it still isn't working for you.

Comment: I have tried many of these things previously, but there are couple of new ideas here I will try out.  I'll respond once I've tested it, thanks.

Comment: I can't get it to work; I'm getting "tunneling socket could not be established, cause=read ECONNRESET". Maybe it's because I'm using atom "portable". I'm not 100% sure in what .apmrc to set the http-proxy stuff. I only got one in the "~(progs/atom)/.atom/.apm" folder but that one says "You should instead edit your .apmrc config located in ~/.atom/.apmrc" yet that file does not exist. If I start an apm config in "Atom/resources/app/apm" it creates a .apmrc in my user directory. I've tried adding the http-proxy in all .apmrc i could find + creating new one in ".atom" folder. But none work.

Comment: If it says you should use `~/.atom/.apmrc` but it doesn't exist, just create it.

Answer (score 4):

You should download the file `http://internal-server-name/sub-dir/file-name.pac` and open it with a text editor, then find the actual proxy address and port inside it (near a `PROXY` keyword).

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  I attempted to do this but was unsuccessful (I received the same errors as before).  Please see my edit to the question for additional detail.

Answer (score 1):

I used this for my trouble with npm and .npmrc

`c:\users\%user%\.atom\.apmrc` (add if not exist) and put this

```
proxy=http://YOUR-DOMAIN**%5C**USER-NAME:PASSWORD@YOUR-PROXY-SERVER:PORT/
```

Comment: Worked for me in Ubuntu Linux by adding a `~/.atom/.apmrc` file as above